# help! Creating a Spreadsheet using a multidimensional array c++

Tags: c++

I have to create a simple spreadsheet program looks like this

```
  A B C D E F G 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4
```

that can set values to cells by user input A1  24.2 ,then set the value 24.2 in A1 and store it,the same user could enter: C3 /, A1, B2 to cause the cell C3 to contain the 
quotient of the contents of cells A1 and B2,

i wonder know how to take a two dimensional array and be able to access the the elements of the array and Displays the spreadsheet with all values entered or calculated
the code i had so far

```
class SpreadSheet{
public:
    const static int nRows = 10;
    const static int nCols = 10;

    SpreadSheet();
    ofstream myFile;
    ifstream retFile;
    void displaySheet();
    void displayFileSheet(char *);
    void refreshFile();
    void inSpreadSheet();
    void setSheet(const string[nRows][nCols]);
    void setCell(int , int, string);
  string getCell(int, int);


private:
    string sheet[nRows][nCols];   
};
```

then i got stuck, any one

Comment: Which particular method is giving you problems?

Comment: The operations that must be implemented are:the arithmetic operations of +,-,*,/

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/csvpp/) instead of reinventing the wheel.